# Normal distribution with a "short" tail

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can someone help me to understand what it means for a normal distribution to have a short/long tail? Google doesn't seem to be helping too much.

Comment: Are you sure it's short/long and not light/heavy?

Comment: Yes, I quote from the test I'm looking at, "Both of its tails are shorter than the corresponding tails of a normal distribution"

Comment: It seems to be the same thing. Look here it's explained: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/histogr2.htm